# Using TcpClient in pcl for xamarin targeting ios and android

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm writing an app which communicates with an embedded linux server via tcp sockets. And I'm looking for a way to write common client code targeting `iOS` and `Android` devices using `Xamarin C#`.

I wanted to know if the `TcpClient` class (`System.Net.Sockets`) can be used in a pcl targeting `iOS` and `Android`. If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283746/net-portable-class-library-and-udp-support

Comment: Thanks @kenny. I looked at that. Looks like Socket class wasn't supported in pcl, atleast until Jan 2013. I found [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2549/tcp-ip-example-for-ios-needed) on xamarin's forum, which shows that the socket class can be used on both ios and android, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just released the first version of a [library](https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl) that wraps over the .NET and WinRT socket implementations, allowing you to write socket code in your PCLs that target Xamarin iOS/Android, Windows Store, Phone and Desktop. Depending on the level of configurability you need, the `TcpSocketClient` class may do the trick.

It relies on the 'Bait and Switch' PCL pattern, so you'll need to install the nuget package in both your PCL project and the native platform projects.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues/requests on the github page!

Comment: rdavisau, You can help me on this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290128/tcp-client-how-to-send-data-to-server-and-return-data-from-server